# Proof of $f(A)=f(A-B)+f(B)$ when $f$ is a injective map

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

I want to prove the following proposition:

Let $A$ be a set, $B$ be a subset of $A$, and $f: A\to B$ be a injective map, then $f(A) = f(A-B) + f(B).$

Could you check my proof below?

Assume $f(A-B)\cap f(B) \neq \emptyset$. For $x\in f(A-B)\cap f(B)$ there exist $a\in A$ which satisfies $f(a)=x$ and $b\in A-B$ which satisfies $f(b)=x$. However, this contradicts the original assumption that $f$ is injective: $\forall a, b \in A, f(a)=f(b)\Rightarrow a=b$, thus the above is impossible. Thus, $f(A-B)\cap f(B)=\emptyset$ and hence $f(A)=f(A-B)+f(B)$.

Comment: Terribly confusing. In the question statement you have a plus sign where a $\cup$ is expected. Then right at the start of your proof you consider an intersection of sets, for some reason. This is followed by a dubious argument and you eventually finalize with incoherent conclusions with no sight of an expected double inclusion proof.

Comment: @GitGud I am so sorry, it was a typo.

Comment: There is another typo: You want to say that there is an $b \in B$ and an $a \in A \setminus B$ such that $f(a) = f(b)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than the typo I've pointed out in a comment, your proof is fine.

Note, however, that you don't need that $B \subseteq A$. The following is true:

*Lemma.* Let $f \colon A \to B$ be injective, $C \subseteq D \subseteq A$ Then 
$$f[D] = f[D \setminus C] \mathbin{\dot{\cup}} f[C].$$

(The proof is virtually the same as the one you've given.)

Also note that injectivity is necessary:

*Lemma.* If $f \colon A \to B$ is not injective, then there is some $C \subseteq A$ such that 
$$f[A \setminus C] \cap f[C] \neq \emptyset.$$

I'll leave the easy proof to you as an exercise. (Hint: You can choose $C$ to be a singleton.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer and exercise! That actually wasn't typo for me (I meant it). Would you explain why I have to write $b\in B, a\in A-B$ instead of just $a, b\in A$?

Comment: @oremata You want to show that $f[A \setminus B] \cap f[B] = \emptyset$. Toward a contradiction you must assume there is some $a \in A \setminus B$ and some $b \in B$ such that $f(a) = f(b)$. If $a \in A \cap B$, it could be that $a = b$ and then there is no contradiction.

Comment: I understand the point. But, before writing about the injection, I mentioned in the proof that there exist $a\in A$ and $b\in A-B$, so I think I don't have to write it again... Is it wrong? Sorry, I'm new to proof stuff.

Comment: @oremata The point is that you could have $a = b$ and then you don't get your contradiction. If you fix $a \in B$ and $b \in A \setminus B$, you know that $a \neq b$ (because $B$ and $A \setminus B$ don't have a common element). If you then have $f(a) = f(b)$, this is a contradiction to injectivity.

Comment: If you want to use a binary operation symbol with an accent on it, it should be coded as `\mathbin{\dot{\cup}}` so the spacing is right.

Comment: Thank you. I understand.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the tip. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that $+$ denotes disjoint union. Your idea is good, but you lose yourself in explanations.

The proof that $f(A)=f(A-B)\cup f(B)$ is easy and doesn't require injectivity.

Now the proof the sets are disjoint. More generally,

> *if $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint sets and $f(X)\cap f(Y)\ne\emptyset$, then $f$ is not injective*.

Indeed, if $z\in f(X)\cap f(Y)$, then $z=f(x)=f(y)$, with $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$. Since $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint, $x\ne y$.